# Object.defineProperties don't work with negative property

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

Briefly,

Changing the properties name of the first example of [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
  1: {
    value: true,
    writable: true
  },
  -1: {
    value: 'Hello',
    writable: false
  }
  // etc. etc.
})
```

we conclude that the script above doesn't work in Chrome and Firefox ( on Debian 9, at least) due to the -1 as property name. The same error doesn't occur with **Object.definePropety**. Illustrating this...

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty( obj, -1 , {value: "Ulalá"} )
```

**Questions:** Is it really not possible to define property with a negative name in this way? Is there some benefits around this behavior (e.g. avoiding incompability with old browser version)?

If this whole question makes sense, I am appalled from not finding any question related to this theme. Nothing related to such behavior was mentioned in MDN page, by googling, no accurate results and in StackOverFlow nothing directly related to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `"-1": {`. Keys are all strings in the end.

Comment: This is just normal for any object literal `{-1: true}` is not valid, `{"-1": true}` is

Comment: Note that there is actually no real "-1", and it is always actually (- operator)1

Comment: Just to show what @user120242 actually means, you can try the same with `+1` which will fail as well. Some methods implement an implicit `toString()` on the key and others not. Which is why some methods succeed where others fail.

Comment: Thanks for all replies!

Now it is clear to me after @user120242's comment. No more doubt.

Comment: Great, @JavaScript! I have understood it. -1 don't create a object. "-" works over 1, what is prohibit in that context (and not in the context given by Object.defineProperty, where -1 appears (in sintatical sense) as a expression.